# Unregister DLL using regsvr32

Tags: registry, regsvr32

This is driving me nuts.

I registered a DLL (COM) using

```
regsvr32 blabla.dll
```

In the meantime, I deleted this DLL manualy from disk.

How can I unregister this dll? I know the CLSID.

Edit:

Apparently I need to delete this from the registry.

What should I delete in the registry?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The unregistration code lives in the DLL, unfortunately, so `regsvr32 /u blabla.dll` won't work; you'll need to manually delete the DLL's information from the Windows registry using `regedit`.  I believe that the registration information is typically located in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{YOUR-CLSID}`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of fixing this is to put the dll back and unregister it.  Then you can delete it.

We often have this at customers places with midas.dll where the registered path does not have the dll.

Answer (score 1):

You unregister a dll the same way you registered it, with the addition of the /u (uninstall) flag.

```
regsvr32 /u blabla.dll
```

Of course if you don't have the dll anymore this won't work, but if you still have a copy or can get one this is easier than manually editing the registry.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to delete the prog.id either located in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT too.